# How to get a substring from command line arguments in netbeans software?

Tags: java

How to get a substring from command line arguments in netbeans software.Netbeans software doesn't support the inbuilt string function substring.kindly help.

Comment: "Netbeans software doesn't support the inbuilt string function substring" - what does you mean?  & define "substring from command line arguments"

Answer (score 0):

pass argument from netbeans

```
project > properties > run > argument > set arguments here
```

and in code

```
args[0].substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
```